# Firefox fails to start on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, firefox, browser

I am unable to start Firefox. Whenever I click on the icon the mouse pointer just changed the state to indicate its busy and the after 2 seconds it would change back to a pointer.

I ran the 'firefox' command in the Terminal and here's the output.

```
vostro-1320:~$ firefox

(process:19047): GLib-CRITICAL **: g_slice_set_config: assertion 'sys_page_size == 0' failed

(firefox:19047): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::sm-connect after class was initialised

(firefox:19047): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::show-crash-dialog after class was initialised

(firefox:19047): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::display after class was initialised

(firefox:19047): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: Attempt to add property GnomeProgram::default-icon after class was initialised

Could not create gnome accelerators directory `/home/bharath/.gnome2/accels': Permission denied
```

Any pointers on what could be wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like the log-in account `bharath` have some permission issue. Change the owner as `bharath` by using

```
sudo chown -R bharath:bharath/home/bharath`
```

and try to open Firefox.

Comment: That works. Fixed the permissions and now all works fine. Thanks!

Comment: Simply creating the accels folder also might work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29856330/453673

Answer (score 1):

Try the following command in your terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>):

```
sudo chown -R "$USER:$USER" "$HOME"
```

This does the same thing as the last answer but does not require editing to make it work on your computer and should be typo free.

Comment: But it assumes that the user that is fixing the problem is the same one that has the problem. And it further assumes that `$HOME` is actually set to the user's home directory, which is far from guaranteed. Even if all that is the case, the user still might not want to change the permissions - especially group ownership - on every single file in his home directory, so it at least should be restricted to `"${HOME}/.gnome/accels`.